# MySQL query some field that is not in another table

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, `members` and `studentexam`. I want to fetch the members who are not registered for an exam. It means they dont have a row in `studentexa` where `examID` is a specific value. I tried this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members                                      
    WHERE accessLevel='student' AND IDNo NOT IN ("SELECT studentID,examID FROM studentexam WHERE examID = $examID")
    ORDER BY family ASC");
```

I have two problems. First, there is a syntax error when use a sql statement into another because of ". I tried ' as well but got error again. the other, I guess if in the inner statement have just `studentID` then got the right result. But in that way I cant use the `where` clause.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**#1** You don't need the `""` around the sub query.

**#2** You don't need to `SELECT` a column to use it in the `WHERE` clause.

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members                                      
    WHERE accessLevel='student' AND IDNo NOT IN (SELECT studentID FROM studentexam WHERE examID = $examID)
    ORDER BY family ASC");
```

You pretty much answered your question yourself :p

Comment: Tanx a lot :). I thought, the `examID` must be selected if it's used in `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 0):

In sub query you dont need to put "" just sub query direct

```
  $result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members                            
WHERE IDNo NOT IN (SELECT studentID FROM studentexam WHERE examID = $examID) ORDER BY family ASC");
```

And that's all you want and you don't need to write accesslevel = 'Student' as i hope that each member would have his unique ID. Writing accesslevel = 'Student' will just increase load on MySQL.

Comment: tanx but I need it coz there are other level members in the `members` table

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the `NOT IN` in this case could be a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT * FROM members m
LEFT JOIN studentexam se ON m.idno = se.studentId
WHERE m.accessLevel = 'student' AND se.studentId IS NULL AND examId = $examID
ORDER BY m.family
```

Comment: Mosty Mostacho : I had problems with the quotations and you simply omitted them